# Libfreenect drivers for ROS

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-fuerte, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to use the old libfreenect drivers on the [ROS.org website](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect). But I can't seem to be able to install them using apt-get install ros-fuerte-kinect. Does anyone know how I can get these drivers?
Moreover, am I able to have libfreenect and openni drivers on the same machine with ROS?

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47103/libfreenect-drivers-for-ros/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has recently been some discussion about this [on the ros-users mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/16856).

In summary, there is on-going work to provide a libfreenect driver that is compatible with the openni driver interfaces.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-10-30**:
A few things have changed since the last discussion. The driver is now documented at http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack. v0.0.2 has been released.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-10-31**:
Thanks a lot Piyushk, I have installed the freenect_stack now and it compiled with zero errors (on one of the two machines in the lab, very strange). I will post a new question with the errors in the libfreenect stack and maybe someone can shed some light on the subject

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey joq,

I went on that website and found some drivers to use from Kevin Walchko @ https://github.com/walchko/kinect.

However, when I try to compile his kinect_camera I get the make error, at first it was an include error looking for the libfreenect.h file. Once I installed libfreenect the compiler gave me these errors:

```
   [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kinect_node.dir/src/kinect_node.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/kinect_node
CMakeFiles/kinect_node.dir/src/kinect_node.cpp.o: In function `kinect_camera::KinectDriver::ok()':
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera/include/kinect_camera/kinect.h:117: undefined reference to `freenect_update_device_state'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera/include/kinect_camera/kinect.h:118: undefined reference to `freenect_get_device_state'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_stop_ir'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_start_rgb'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_stop_rgb'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_set_rgb_format'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_start_ir'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_set_rgb_callback'
../lib/libkinect_driver.so: undefined reference to `freenect_set_ir_callback'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/kinect_node] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/kinect_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@ubuntu:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/kinect_camera#
```

It seems as though the libfreenect.h header file (installed through the libfreenect openKinect website) is different than the libfreenect header file used in Kevin's codes.

Are there different libfreenect header files? or am I doing something wrong here...

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

Originally posted by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) with karma: 464 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-10-30**:
So ... did you use my [freenect library](https://github.com/walchko/libfreenect) ... it is basically a forked version willow garage made. I have a homebrew formula in there to install it to Mac OSX ... works fine. I have not tired it on linux though.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-10-30**:
The readme should have explained all of this. Right now I am in the process of getting ROS up and running on RaspberryPi (ARM) and will get it libfreenect working (eventually) on ARM linux, but that won't be for a while. Maybe try [Piyush's](https://github.com/piyushk/freenect_stack). Good luck!

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-10-30**:
Hey Kevin, we tried downloading Piyush's drivers and then used rosmake freenect_stack and it came up with a whole bunch of errors as well. Is there something else we need to install before trying to install these stacks?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-10-30**:
@MartinW: see updated comment on @joq's answer. Installation instructions are on the ros wiki. If they do not work, then please file a bug report.